# Prime numbers in factorizations of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, prime-gaps, distribution-of-primes

I would like to know if the following affirmation is true or not: If M is a set of consecutive natural numbers there is a prime number in the factorization of one of M's elements that doesn't divide any other element in the set.

Comment: $n$ and $(n+1)$ are always coprime. This is a start. I think that if it's true, it should be possible to extend an argument one by one.

Comment: Follow the proof of exercise 9 [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3588) and generalize it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For $k=17$ there exists a sequence of $k$ consecutive integers without a number relatively prime to all others.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2008-77-264/S0025-5718-08-02134-0/S0025-5718-08-02134-0.pdf) *A classic theorem of Sylvester states that the product of $k$ consecutive integers
is necessarily divisible by a prime $p>k$*

Comment: @reuns The product of $k$ consecutive integers GREATER THAN $k$ is divisible by a prime greater than $k$ is necessarily divisible by a prime $p>k$.

Comment: @RobertZ I should have precised greater than $k$, but it doesn't change the solution to OP's problem because the case $[k,2k-1]$ and $[n,2k-1], n < k$ is solved with Bertrand postulate.

Comment: @reuns According to your statement $k!$ is divisible by a prime $p>k$.

Answer (score 0):

For the original question, where the word consecutive was not included:  It is not true.  Take $M=\{6,10,15\}$

Comment: i mean consecutive numbers, but i forgot to say so and i have edited the question

Comment: That changes the question completely.

Comment: yes it does, sorry for not mentioning it in the first place